# Lights working only in render and not in viewport

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, lighting

I have been working on a render of a laptop. So far everything went well until I got into lighting the scene. Any light I add (be it spot light, area light and so on...) is not working in the viewport rendered view but works in the final render. I have been stuck on this for a couple of hours so far and I didn't make any progress. Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

This is a screen of a spotlight not showing up in rendered view:
[image: Blender viewport]

And this is the final render with spotlight visible:
[image: Render]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure [this option](https://imgur.com/a/ja5imYI) is checked in the Viewport Shading options:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently in `Local View` mode. Since a while, Blender also respects which of your lights are in local view, and skips the others.

Press the <kbd>/</kbd> key on your numpad while your mouse cursor is over the 3D ViewPort to exit `Local View`, or use the `View` menu of you 3D ViewPort, and under `Local View` find the option `Toggle Local View`.

Comment: Yes! That was it! I must've clicked the slash accidentally at some point. Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Enable lights here in the shading popover:

[image]